# In Unity3D inputField is treated as a placeholder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

**My goal**: Place the value from sqlite database into the inputField as text.  I want the user to be able to update the record/value of that database.  Baically, I am trying to make a note app kinda like note on iPhone.

**My issue**: The text shows up in the field inside the text and contentfield, including the input cursor/caret. When the user clicks on the text field it resets everything to empty.

**What I have tried**:  I created a script that will change the value of text inside the inputField to a value fetched from the database.  The text gets updated as expected.  Then as soon as I or other users press on the inputField the value dissapears, similar to how a placeholder works.  However, I want the value to stay in place so the user can edit it.

the code:

```
TextMeshProUGUI contenttext =
  input1.transform.Find("Text").GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
contenttext.text = source;
```

This is suppose to update the `text` component, which is a child of `text area` which is a child of `contentfield`.  Here are [before](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M8z4e148L6eYBoDyr2ynZ4aMwzYT0V6G) and [after](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V4bO1_kMWkB1OrIOxesoLM1Gq685GPJc) pictures of the inspector.

Comment: Your problem is that `GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();` simply returns the first component of that type found which rather seems to be the one for the placeholder, not the actual text. Usually you rather do `inputField.text = "...";` instead of "manually" going through the text component directly

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to `Find()` the gameobject containing the `TextMeshProUGUI` and calling `.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>`? Why get it's child's component?

Comment: @derhugo it still give the same effect.

Comment: @innat3 this was another way instead of looking throught everyobject with find(). you can look into a child of an object that you are already set.

Comment: @alde now that I think about if you want to set the text of the InputField you HAVE TO set it in the `text` property of the `TMP_InputField` component, not `TextMeshProUGUI`

Comment: can you please reopen this question. i provided more detail

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value in the `.text` field of the `TMP_InputField`, not the `TextMeshProUGUI`

```
input1.transform.Find("Text").GetComponentInChildren<TMP_InputField>().text = source;
```